# How to get this Gmail style swipe to delete effect using jQuery without the AngularJS code

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, html

This is exactly what I'm looking for, but am trying to accomplish it using just jQuery:
http://codepen.io/winkerVSbecks/pen/zfbiE

```
  <head>
<title>Swipe-Li - a swipeable checklist</title>
```

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="accept-content.html">
  <div class="icon-ok"></div>  
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="reject-content.html">
  <div class="icon-cancel"></div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="sample-content.html">
  <div class="main-content">{{item.name}}</div>
</script>

<div class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <h1>
  Swipe-Li <small>a swipeable checklist</small>
    <a href="https://github.com/winkerVSbecks/swipe-li">github</a>
  </h1>

  <div ng-repeat="item in list">
    <div
      swipe-li
      class="item"
      disabled=""
      intent="true"
      accept="done(item)"
      reject="skip(item)"
      main-content="'sample-content.html'"
      accept-content="'accept-content.html'"
      reject-content="'reject-content.html'"
      reset-to-content="false"
      ng-class="{invert: item.doInvert}"
    ></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Dependencies -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/1.1.3/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
<!-- endDependencies -->

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="swipe-li/swipe-li.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<!-- endscripts -->

<!-- GA -->
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-22315045-8', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- END GA -->
```

```
'use strict';
```

angular.module('swipeLiDemo', [
  'swipeLi'
])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

```
$scope.list = [
{
  name: 'Spectacles',
  doInvert: false
},
{
  name: 'Giraffe',
  doInvert: false
},
{
  name: 'Turtle',
  doInvert: false
},
{
  name: 'Shark',
  doInvert: false
},
{
  name: 'Lamp',
  doInvert: false
},
{
  name: 'Chocolate',
  doInvert: false
},
{
  name: 'Beef',
  doInvert: false
},
{
  name: 'Drawer',
  doInvert: false
},
{
  name: 'Brocolli',
  doInvert: false
},
{
  name: 'Tomato',
  doInvert: false
},
{
  name: 'Plate',
  doInvert: false
},
{
  name: 'Zebra',
  doInvert: false
}];

$scope.doInvert = false;

$scope.done = function (item) {
  console.log('%s marked as accepted!', item);
  item.doInvert = true;
};

$scope.skip = function (item) {
  console.log('%s marked as rejected!', item);
  item.doInvert = true;
};
```

}]);

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first option is to find a jQuery plugin that does it. You might find it here:

- http://www.javascripting.com/
- http://www.unheap.com/

Another option is to extract the logic from the `swipe-li` directive, here is a link to the [source code](https://github.com/winkerVSbecks/swipe-li/blob/master/src/swipe-li.js#L15), but you'll might need to know a bit of angular, and how the `$scope` works.

The swip-li project has an MIT license.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, much appreciated. I ended up just using something similar to this [link](http://codepen.io/mochiron/pen/Jatrb)